# how does lodash's _.parseInt parses safely on map

Tags: javascript, lodash

I was reading a blog that states _.parseInt is safe.
As per the documentation it also accepts the radix as second argument as the native parseInt does.
Generally on mapping an array, one can encounter unexpected behaviour when directly passing parseInt to map.

How does lodash's parseInt work safely?

```
var a = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']

//case 1:    
_.map(a, parseInt)
//[2, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN] -  this is the expected output

//case 2:    
_.map(a, (num, index) => _.parseInt(num, index))
//[2, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN] -  this is the expected output

//case 3:    
_.map(a, _.parseInt)
//[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] -  how is this working correctly?
```

Also how is case 2 different from case 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The implementation](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/912d6b04a1f6b732508a6da72a95ec4f96bda154/lodash.js#L14455) of `_.parseInt` takes a "secret" *third* argument.

If this third argument is provided, like in a `_.map(a, _.parseInt)` callback, the second argument is ignored.

```js
var a = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'];

// With two arguments:
console.log(_.map(a, (num, index) => _.parseInt(num, index)));
//[2, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN] -  this is the expected output

// With all three arguments that _.map provides:
console.log(_.map(a, (num, index, arr) => _.parseInt(num, index, arr)));
//[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, I saw that in source code after posting the question, but was this specially done to make it work for map, reduce, etc?

Comment: I can't imagine any other reason for it. Thre's [this comment by jdalton](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/992#issuecomment-75661057) that also indicates so.